# VBA Project of Powerpoint Presentation not Saved after importing slides from other presentation

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint presentation with macros which allows users to add modules which are sections of a big presentation. Both the main presentation and the modules are saved as `.pptm` files.

The modules are imported using the [Slides.InsertFromFile-Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.insertfromfile) into the main presentation.

Sometimes, after saving the presentation, closing it and reopen it the VBA-Project is not visible anymore:
[image: Picture of missing VBA-project]

Additionally, after inspecting the presentation as a .zip file, it turns out that the vbaProject.bin file is still there:
[image: Picture of the directory structure of the .pptm file]

This bug does not occur predictably, however, the chances of this bug occuring is higher if more modules are loaded into the presentation.
The modules are created from the main presentation by copying it, removing all slides except the ones for the section that make up a module. Thus, all modules use the same slide master.

Is there anything that could be the cause for this bug and methods to solve it?

#### Update:

Here is the VBA code used to import a 'module'. A 'module' in this case is just a Powerpoint presentation containing slides. The modules can contain VBA code for dropdowns in certain slides and cases like this where the VBA code is slide-specific and used to control certain user-elements. The modules are referred to as sections in the code and the idea is to import sections from a big presentation selectively.

```
Sub ImportSection(sectionName As String, sectionPath As String, sectionId As String)

    Dim iFAP As Presentation, sectionPres As Presentation
    Dim sectionIndex As Long, currSection As Long, currSectionName As String
    Dim slideIndex As Long, currSlideIndex As Long
    Dim LastSlide As Integer

    Set iFAP = ActivePresentation
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sectionPres = GetObject(sectionPath)
    If sectionPres Is Nothing Then
        ' Presentation could not be found
        Wait 3
        GoTo Error
    End If
    
    ' Get the selected section index from the list box
    sectionIndex = GetSectionOrderIndex(sectionName)
    
    If sectionIndex > 1 Then
        With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
            LastSlide = (.FirstSlide(sectionIndex - 1) + .SlidesCount(sectionIndex - 1)) - 1
        End With
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Actual import code 
    iFAP.Slides.InsertFromFile sectionPath, LastSlide
    
    With sectionPres.SectionProperties
        For sectionI = 1 To .count
            currSlideIndex = LastSlide + .FirstSlide(sectionI)
            currSectionName = .name(sectionI)
            iFAP.SectionProperties.AddBeforeSlide currSlideIndex, currSectionName
            iFAP.Slides(currSlideIndex).CustomLayout = FindCustomLayout(CleanSectionName(currSectionName))
        Next sectionI
    End With
    
    sectionPres.Close
Error:
End Sub
```

Furthermore, to import multiple sections, we have a userform in the presentation with checkboxes, which we loop through to import every checked section using the function above.

Comment: It would be good to show us the code importing slides in discussion. Then, you are talking about slides importing, but what do you mean by "if more modules are loaded into the presentation"? Are you talking about VBA modules or something else? Do the imported slides contain VBA code?

Comment: I've added the code to import a 'module' or 'section'. This is just a term to refer to a small presentation like a chapter in a book. Most of the code is just there to add the section markers into the presentation. The actual code to import the slide of a section is a simple function call.

Comment: I'm not clear why you included an Excel tag, I don't see any Excel code. 


It sounds like you're importing slides into the presentation that contains the code. In most cases, it's a better practice to save your code in a VBA add-in (*.ppam), then install that in PowerPoint. Then the code can't get wiped out by changes you make to the presentation being worked on.